# Como puedo realizar la siguiente consulta con Query Builder Laravel 5.5

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

Tengo la siguiente consulta en mysql.

```
 SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (select SUM(tabla1.campo1) from `tabla1` inner
 join `tabla2` on `tabla1`.`tabla1_id` = `tabla2`.`tabla2_id` where
`tabla1`.`campo1` <> 0 group by LOWER(tabla1.campo2)) tabla_general
```

¿Como puedo transcribirla a Query Builder en Laravel 5.5?.
Gracias.

Comment: Prueba algo así: `$total = DB::table('tabla1')->selectRaw('SUM(tabla1.campo1), LOWER(tabla1.campo2)')
        ->join('tabla2', 'tabla1.tabla1_id', '=', 'tabla2.tabla2_id)
        ->where('tabla1.campo1', '<>', 0)
        ->groupBy('tabla1.campo2')
        ->count();`

Comment: Genial, me ayudo bastante. Gracias por responder.

Comment: La publico como respuesta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes intertar algo así:

```
$total = DB::table('tabla1')->selectRaw('SUM(tabla1.campo1), LOWER(tabla1.campo2)')
  ->join('tabla2', 'tabla1.tabla1_id', '=', 'tabla2.tabla2_id')
  ->where('tabla1.campo1', '<>', 0)
  ->groupBy('tabla1.campo2')
  ->count();
```